# Cannot install libdgiplus on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg

My head is already blowing up. 
I'm trying to install libgdiplus on Ubuntu 16.04 but all my attempts to do so seem to be useless. 
Here's what I'm getting all the time

```
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# root@a1-03-s08-11:~# sudo apt-get install libgdiplus                            Reading package lists... Done
-bash: root@a1-03-s08-11:~#: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# Building dependency tree
-bash: Building: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# Reading state information... Done
-bash: Reading: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
-bash: You: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# The following packages have unmet dependencies:
-bash: The: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~#  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic but it is not going to be installed
-bash: linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~#  linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic but it is not going to be installed
-bash: linux-image-generic: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~#                        Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
-bash: Recommends:: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# root@a1-03-s08-11:~# apt-get -f install
-bash: root@a1-03-s08-11:~#: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# Reading package lists... Done
-bash: Reading: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# Building dependency tree
-bash: Building: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# Reading state information... Done
-bash: Reading: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# Correcting dependencies... Done
-bash: Correcting: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# The following additional packages will be installed:
-bash: The: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~#   linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic
-bash: linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# Suggested packages:
-bash: Suggested: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~#   fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools
-bash: linux-source-4.4.0: command not found
-bash: fdutils: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~#   linux-headers-4.4.0-141-generic
-bash: linux-headers-4.4.0-141-generic: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# The following NEW packages will be installed:
-bash: The: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~#   linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic
-bash: linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 57 not upgraded.
-bash: 0: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# 2 not fully installed or removed.
-bash: 2: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# Need to get 0 B/22.2 MB of archives.
-bash: Need: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# After this operation, 68.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
-bash: After: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
-bash: Do: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# (Reading database ... 220941 files and directories currently installed.)
-bash: Reading: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic_4.4.0-141.167_amd64.deb ...
-bash: Preparing: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
-bash: Examining: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 4.4.0-141-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
-bash: run-parts:: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# Done.
-bash: Done.: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic (4.4.0-141.167) ...-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic_4.4.0-141.167_amd64.deb (--unpack):
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
root@a1-03-s08-11:~#  unable to clean up mess surrounding './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic' before installing another version: Read-only file system
-bash: unable: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
-bash: Examining: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-141-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
-bash: run-parts:: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-141-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
-bash: run-parts:: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# Errors were encountered while processing:
-bash: Errors: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~#  /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic_4.4.0-141.167_amd64.deb
-bash: /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic_4.4.0-141.167_amd64.deb: Permission denied
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
root@a1-03-s08-11:~# root@a1-03-s08-11:~#
-bash: root@a1-03-s08-11:~#: command not found
root@a1-03-s08-11:~#
```

After this, whatever I try to install, I keep getting some dependency errors. I can't even update packages. 
I wanted to upgrade kernel, with the same result

Comment: I assume `root@a1-03-s08-11:~#` is the prompt you get in the terminal. In line 1, you've typed command like `root@a1-03-s08-11:~# sudo apt-get install libgdiplus`. Why are you using username@hostname while installing a package? Simply run `sudo apt-get install libgdiplus`. It looks like you're using "the output" of some command as a command. Kindly use `sudo apt-get install libgdiplus` only and paste the output of that only. Don't try to run the output as command. That would through errors and make the output look messy.

Comment: It looks like you're pasting a set of instructions *including comments and shell prompts* into your terminal - don't do that

Comment: And why are you root and using sudo?

Comment: @Kulfy, nope, it's not an output of any command, everything is correct there. I've already resolved this issue. It was in a Read-only state of the filesystem. I've posted my answer below :)

Comment: @steeldriver, no, I don't do that. All those comments come from the output

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved. 
I couldn't install those dependencies because the /boot was mounted as read-only. 
I've mounted it as read-write like this `mount -o remount,rw /boot` 
and manged to install everything I needed. That's it. This simple :)

I actually saw this error, but I tried to mount it like this `mount -o remount,rw ./boot` 
at first, and it didn't work